# Getting last 10 days with timestamp for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to create a script that get the previous records from yesterday up to 10 days but cant do it.

I have a table called `user_stats_clicks` and a column named `dsub` that is a timstamp

This is what tried.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `user_stats_clicks` 
WHERE  `dsub` = CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 
DAY ORDER BY  `user_stats_clicks`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But it keeps on returning zero results.

How do I get the records from yesterday up to 10 days earlier?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only currently specifying half of the date range. You also need to specify the start of the date range as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM  `user_stats_clicks` 
WHERE  (`dsub` < CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
AND  `dsub` >= CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
ORDER BY  `user_stats_clicks`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM  `user_stats_clicks` 
WHERE  (`dsub` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 DAY 
              AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY  `user_stats_clicks`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT * FROM  `user_stats_clicks` 
    WHERE  (`date` < CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    AND  `date` >= CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
ORDER BY  `user_stats_clicks`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and also i just worked on [**MYSQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5421f/4) check it out

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `user_stats_clicks` 
WHERE  `dsub` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE() 
DAY ORDER BY  `user_stats_clicks`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```